# Getting distance between the camera and an exact object

Tags: java, opengl

When we need to get the distance between camera ant a 3D object on witch we are pointing we use `GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`. The problem is that i want to get the distance between the camera and an object behind the object closest to the camera. Is it possible to do that? How?

Answer (score 2):

*This is becomming my most oftenly written OpenGL clarification:*

**OpenGL is not a scene graph. It merely draws points, lines and triangles to a 2D framebuffer**. There's no such thing like objects or a camera in OpenGL. There's only geometry primitives, which OpenGL forgets about the moment it rasterized them, and the result of this process in the framebuffer. OpenGL has no notion of "in front" or "behind".

What you're asking about is completely outside the scope of OpenGL. What you want is a scene graph implementing ray - triangle intersection picking.

And I can only reiterate what Nicol Bolas already answered:

> OpenGL is for rendering; it's for drawing stuff. It's depth buffer exists for that purpose. **And the depth buffer only stores the distance from the Z-plane of the camera**, ***not the radial distance from the point to that point on the triangle***.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the distance between two points (like the camera and the center point of an object), then you're going to have to compute it with regular vector math: `sqrt(dot(pt1 - pt2, pt1 - pt2))`

OpenGL is for rendering; it's for drawing stuff. It's depth buffer exists for that purpose. And the depth buffer only stores the distance from the Z-plane of the camera, not the radial distance from the point to that point on the triangle.